# Error of input at character 1 of

Tags: java, php, android

I'm fetching records from mysql database and putting it into a ListView but I'm getting the said error stated in the title, "Error of input at character 1 of". I already tried checking the php file associated with it but it's working well and able to fetch data from the db. Below is the code where the error is being caught.

```
public void ListDrawer() {
    List<Map<String, String>> announcementList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> listA;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("myannouncement");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = jsonChildNode.optString("title");
            String dated = jsonChildNode.optString("dated");
            String description = jsonChildNode.optString("description");
            String id = jsonChildNode.optString("announcement_id");

            listA = new HashMap<String, String>();
            listA.put("title", title);
            listA.put("dated", dated);
            listA.put("description", description);
            listA.put("id", id);

            announcementList.add(listA);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage().toString() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

*

```
*

01-06 02:12:04.696: W/System.err(557): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2 refused
    01-06 02:12:04.706: W/System.err(557):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
    01-06 02:12:04.706: W/System.err(557):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    01-06 02:12:04.706: W/System.err(557):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    01-06 02:12:04.706: W/System.err(557):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    01-06 02:12:04.716: W/System.err(557):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    01-06 02:12:04.716: W/System.err(557):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    01-06 02:12:04.716: W/System.err(557):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    01-06 02:12:04.716: W/System.err(557):  at com.feufern.apms.AnnouncementActivity$JsonReadTask.doInBackground(AnnouncementActivity.java:59)
    01-06 02:12:04.716: W/System.err(557):  at com.feufern.apms.AnnouncementActivity$JsonReadTask.doInBackground(AnnouncementActivity.java:1)
    01-06 02:12:04.726: W/System.err(557):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
    01-06 02:12:04.726: W/System.err(557):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    01-06 02:12:04.726: W/System.err(557):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    01-06 02:12:04.726: W/System.err(557):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
    01-06 02:12:04.736: W/System.err(557):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    01-06 02:12:04.736: W/System.err(557):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    01-06 02:12:04.736: W/System.err(557):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    01-06 02:12:04.746: W/System.err(557): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
    01-06 02:12:04.746: W/System.err(557):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
    01-06 02:12:04.756: W/System.err(557):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    01-06 02:12:04.756: W/System.err(557):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    01-06 02:12:04.756: W/System.err(557):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    01-06 02:12:04.756: W/System.err(557):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
    01-06 02:12:04.756: W/System.err(557):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
    01-06 02:12:04.756: W/System.err(557):  ... 15 more
    01-06 02:12:04.766: W/System.err(557): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
    01-06 02:12:04.776: W/System.err(557):  at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    01-06 02:12:04.776: W/System.err(557):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
    01-06 02:12:04.776: W/System.err(557):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    01-06 02:12:04.786: W/System.err(557):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    01-06 02:12:04.786: W/System.err(557):  ... 20 more
    01-06 02:12:04.796: D/AndroidRuntime(557): Shutting down VM
    01-06 02:12:04.796: W/dalvikvm(557): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557): java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.feufern.apms.AnnouncementActivity.ListDrawer(AnnouncementActivity.java:109)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.feufern.apms.AnnouncementActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(AnnouncementActivity.java:90)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.feufern.apms.AnnouncementActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(AnnouncementActivity.java:1)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    01-06 02:12:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*

*

Comment: can you show your json?

Comment: Post the actual error message/logcat/stacktrace, whatever you got.

Comment: I already included the logcat

Comment: `jsonResult` is null when you call `JSONObject` constructor